# ngrx state is undefined if not named

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm getting the hang of ngrx, and I've got it work... but I had a heck of a time doing it and it's wrong compared to every tutorial/walkthrough that I've seen online and I'd like to see if I can get it to a correct state.

My problems are 2 fold:

1. If I don't give the state a name, it's undefined in the browser. This works:

```
import { reducers } from './state/app.reducers';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({ appState: reducers }),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)` like most examples show, results in undefined state at runtime.

2. I believe that, because if this, I can't reference state at the root and have to pluck it out. For example, this works:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  state$: Observable<AppState>;
  userId$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<{appState: AppState}>
  ) {
    this.state$ = store.select('appState');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userId$ = this.state$.pipe(select(s => s.userId));
  }
}
```

I can't select off the state directly, like most examples include, and it won't work at all injecting just `private store Store<AppState>` like most examples show.

If it helps, my state, at runtime, looks like this:

```
{
  appState: {
    userId: 'd229b5ef-b7a8-2600-6eed-427ee7b10637',
    userName: 'test',
  }
}
```

For reference...

```
// app/state/app.state.ts
export interface AppState {
  userId: string;
  userName: string;
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
  userId: null,
  userName: null
}
```

```
// app/state/app.reducers.ts
import { initialState } from './app.state';

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(updateUser, (state, { userId, userName })=> (
    {
      ...state,
      userId: userId,
      userName: userName
    }))
);

export function reducers(state, action) {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

```
// app/state/app.selectors.ts
import { AppState } from './app.state';

export const selectUserId = (state: AppState) => state.userId
```

So I'm a bit at a loss. I've got it working, where I can store state and get it at runtime, but it's not idiomatic, and it seems to be very brittle.

Comment: please refer official doc https://ngrx.io/guide/store for point 5.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're exporting one reducer as reducers and then trying to use it. You need to export that one reducers and create an array of reducers that you will use as the reducers in your `StoreModule.forRoot()`. Code example:

```js
// app/state/app.reducers.ts
import { initialState } from './app.state';

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(updateUser, (state, { userId, userName })=> (
    {
      ...state,
      userId: userId,
      userName: userName
    }))
);

export function reducer(state, action) { // changed from 'reducers' to reducer
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

Create a new file called `index.ts`:

```js
// app/state/index.ts

import * as fromApp from 'app/state/app.reducer.ts',

export const reducers = [
  appState: fromApp.reducer
]
```

Then import the reducers:

```js
import { reducers } from './state/index.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't seem to work/help much. The outcome is that it sets the named state to '0' instead of appState and my selectors don't work anymore either. I appreciate the help, but ngrx just seems to be too unstable. It's a house of cards and if one thing is out of place, the whole thing comes crashing down and there's very little way to determine what's going on. I'll be abandoning it as a state management solution.